# How can I integrate sonarqube to a azure CI

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I just wanted to know how should I integrate sonarqube to azure devops CI pipeline.

Anonther question, is it free or not, to do that ?

Sorry or my bad english

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Of [the official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/azuredevops-integration/) you can find steps for implementing SonarQube on Azure DevOps.